# NPM error installing "sse4_crc32"

Tags: node.js, npm

I was initially getting this error as a dependency for a different package, but it fails when I try it on its own too. Since it's the first time I'm trying to install a node.js package, I'm sure I'm missing something, but what?

```
$ npm install --save sse4_crc32
\
> sse4_crc32@3.3.0 install /home/agam/node_modules/sse4_crc32
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/agam/node_modules/sse4_crc32/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sse4_crc32/src/sse4_crc32.o
In file included from ../src/sse4_crc32.cpp:18:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In constructor ‘Nan::Utf8String::Utf8String(v8::Local)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1178:27: error: ‘REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
                           v8::String::REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8;
                           ^
sse4_crc32.target.mk:87: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/sse4_crc32/src/sse4_crc32.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sse4_crc32/src/sse4_crc32.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/agam/node_modules/sse4_crc32/build'
```

Comment: What your node version?

Comment: $ nodejs -v
v0.10.38

Comment: You mentioned `nodejs` as your executable, but do you also have a `node` executable? Does `node -v` show a different version?

Comment: /usr/bin/node is symlinked to nodejs; not sure if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same issue today.

I was on Node 0.10.29 which supposedly should work.
Upgraded to Node 0.10.38 but that didn't solve the problem.

I was running on debian (jessy) and there npm was installed pulling in a old version of node-gyp as a dependency. 0.2.0 I believe for npm 1.4.x.

Installing a new version of node-gyp through npm install -g solved the problem. (After some symlink changes to point to the new node-gyp).

Comment: can you explain exactly the commands you entered in the command line to install a new version and to symlink things? otherwise I cannot really upvote here, not a very specific answer

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you're using node v0.11.12 or an earlier v0.11 release which would not have `v8::String::REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8` (which is available since v0.11.13 when v8 was upgraded to 3.24.x from 3.22.x). node v0.11.x versions are considered unstable and you should upgrade to at least v0.12. After that, the error should go away.

The more technical reason for the error is that `nan` simply does [a check if the node ABI version is post-v0.10](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/a44309b51d12e992755ce8c8e27a89bd07289f56/nan.h#L500) around the code that uses `v8::String::REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8`, so it assumes you're using v0.12 or newer, where that constant is available.

Comment: I see `npm` at version 1.4.21, `node-js` at version 0.10.38, and `node-gyp` at version 0.12.2.

Comment: I just tried with node v0.10.40 and have no issue installing `sse4_crc32`.